# Falta traduzir o newsletter semanal

Tags: bug, internacionalização, newsletter

Percebi hoje que o *newsletter* semanal do Stack-PT ainda não foi traduzido.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]